# Show that two topologies coincide on a subset

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, nets

Let $E$ be a set, $\tau_i$ be a topology on $E$ and $B\subseteq E$.

> I wonder how we would need to show that $$\left.\tau_1\right|_B:=\{\Omega\cap B:\Omega\in\tau_1\}=\{\Omega\cap B:\Omega\in\tau_2\}=\left.\tau_2\right|_B\tag1.$$

I already know the following:

> **Lemma 1**: The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$;
> 2. $\operatorname{id}_E$ is $(\tau_2,\tau_1)$-continuous;
> 3. If $x\in E$ is a $\tau_2$-limit point of a net $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq E$, then $x$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$.

So, from this we immediately obtain that the following are equivalent:

4. $\tau_1=\tau_2$;
5. $\operatorname{id}_E$ is a homeomorphism from $(E,\tau_1)$ onto $(E,\tau_2)$;
6. If $x\in E$ and $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq E$ is a net, then $x$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$ if and only if $x$ is a $\tau_2$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$.

> So, I guess we need to find a characterization of the net convergence in a subspace topology. Let $\tau$ be any topology on $E$, $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq B$ be a net and $x\in B$.
>
> Are we able to show that
> 7. $x$ is a $\left.\tau\right|_B$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$;
> 8. $x$ is a $\tau$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$
>
> are equivalent?

This should be correct: Assume (7.) and let $N$ be a $\tau$-neighborhood of $x$. Then there is a $\Omega\in\tau$ with $x\in\Omega\subseteq N$ and, since $x\in B$, $O:=\Omega\cap B$ is a $\left.\tau\right|_B$-neighborhood of $x$. So, by (7.)$, $$\exists t_0\in I:\forall t\ge t_0:x_t\in O\subseteq\Omega\subseteq N;$$ i.e. (8.).

Now assume (8.) and let $N$ be a $\left.\tau\right|_B$-neighborhood of $x$. Then there is a $\Omega\in\tau$ with $x\in O:=\Omega\cap B\subseteq N$ and obviously $\Omega$ is a $\tau$-neighborhood of $x$. So, by (8.), $$\exists t_0\in I:\forall t\ge t_0:x_t\in\Omega.$$ Since $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq B$, we conclude $$\forall t\ge t_0:x_t\in\Omega\cap B=O\subseteq N;$$ i.e. (7.).

> So, $(1)$ should be equivalent to
>
> 8. If $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq B$ is a net and $x\in B$, then $x$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$ if and only if $x$ is a $\tau_2$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$,
>
> right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s correct, but you can shorten it considerably. For $i\in\{1,2\}$ let $\tau_i^B$ be the relative topology on $B$ induced by $\tau_i$. It’s trivial that if $\tau_1^B=\tau_2^B$, $\nu$ is a net in $B$, and $p\in B$, then $\nu$ converges to $p$ in $\tau_1^B$ iff if $\nu$ converges to $p$ in $\tau_2^B$.

For the converse, suppose that $\tau_1^B\ne\tau_2^B$. Without loss of generality there is some $U\in\tau_1^B\setminus\tau_2^B$. Let $F=B\setminus U$; $F$ is not closed in $\tau_2^B$. Since $F$ is not closed in $\tau_2^B$, there is a $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_{\tau_2^B}F)\setminus F$, and there is a net $\nu$ in $F$ converging to $p$ in $\tau_2^B$. In $\tau_1^B$, however, $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$ that contains no term of the net $\nu$, so $\nu$ does not converge to $p$ in $\tau_1^B$.

Thus, $\tau_1^B=\tau_2^B$ iff $\left\langle B,\tau_1^B\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle B,\tau_2^B\right\rangle$ have the same convergent nets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you've got my question wrong. It seems like you've shown the general fact that if $E$ is a topological space and $\tau_i$ is a topology on $E$, then $\tau_1=\tau_2$ if and only if $(E,\tau_1)$ and $(E,\tau_2)$ have the same convergent nets (you just have shown this for the particular case of two subspace topologies). That's precisely the equivalence between (4.) and (6.) I've mentioned above. My actual question was if (8.) is equivalent to $(1)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The equivalence between $(8)$ and $(1)$ is what I proved. It is simply a special case of the general equivalence between $(4)$ and $(6)$.

Comment: Hm, it would only be a special case if I you replace "$\tau_i$" with "$\left.\tau_i\right|_B$" in (8.). But as it is written, it is not a special case (though it might immediately follow).

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Convergence of a net in $B$ to a point in $B$ is trivially determined completely by what happens in $B$, i.e., by the topology of $B$ as a space.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking for and I see that it's rather trivial now.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sorry; I didn’t realize until now *why* you were going the long way round, or I’d have addressed it directly.